# Admin panel images not showing in Oscommerce

Tags: php, e-commerce, oscommerce

I have Oscommerce based site which is showing up all the images of the site in frontend ,but in the admin panel the images(product images) is not showing up ,i've given below /catalog/admin/includes/configure.php file below.

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://mysite.com');
  define('HTTP_CATALOG_SERVER', 'http://mysite.com');
  define('HTTPS_CATALOG_SERVER', 'http://mysite.com');
  define('ENABLE_SSL_CATALOG', 'false');
  define('DIR_FS_DOCUMENT_ROOT', '/home3/hearworl/public_html/shop_now/catalog/');
  define('DIR_WS_ADMIN', '/shop_now/catalog/admin/');
  define('DIR_FS_ADMIN', '/home3/hearworl/public_html/shop_now/catalog/admin/');
  define('DIR_WS_CATALOG', '/home3/hearworl/public_html/shop_now/catalog/');
  define('DIR_FS_CATALOG', '/home3/hearworl/public_html/shop_now/catalog/');
  define('DIR_WS_IMAGES', 'images/');
  define('DIR_WS_ICONS', DIR_WS_IMAGES . 'icons/');
  define('DIR_WS_CATALOG_IMAGES', DIR_WS_CATALOG . 'images/');
  define('DIR_WS_INCLUDES', 'includes/');
  define('DIR_WS_BOXES', DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'boxes/');
  define('DIR_WS_FUNCTIONS', DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'functions/');
  define('DIR_WS_CLASSES', DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'classes/');
  define('DIR_WS_MODULES', DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'modules/');
  define('DIR_WS_LANGUAGES', DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'languages/');
  define('DIR_WS_CATALOG_LANGUAGES', DIR_WS_CATALOG . 'includes/languages/');
  define('DIR_FS_CATALOG_LANGUAGES', DIR_FS_CATALOG . 'includes/languages/');
  define('DIR_FS_CATALOG_IMAGES', DIR_FS_CATALOG . 'images/');
  define('DIR_FS_CATALOG_MODULES', DIR_FS_CATALOG . 'includes/modules/');
  define('DIR_FS_BACKUP', DIR_FS_ADMIN . 'backups/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes sense, but the provided configuration data means nothing to anyone not looking at your actual server.

A quick recommendation I would make would be to install Firefox (if you aren't using it already) and the Firebug Add-On (again, if not already using it). Then right-click on the area where the image should be displayed and select "Inspect Element" to review the HTML/CSS and see the URL for the image. Try and view the image directly to ensure that the file is valid and accessible. If not, review the image URL, your folders/files, permissions, etc.

Comment: Actually i got partial success in retieving the images .. currently the path of the images is  '/home3/hearworl/public_html/shop_now/catalog/images/SA-SBB500SS.jpg'  when it changed to '/shop_now/catalog/images/SA-SBB500SS.jpg' images are showing up..but i dont know where to change the path

Comment: [SOLVED] As suggested by the Lucanos i  just changed the define('DIR_WS_CATALOG', '/home3/hearworl/public_html/shop_now/catalog/'); to   define('DIR_WS_CATALOG', '/shop_now/catalog/');
 Its working ,Thanks to Lucanos

Answer (score 1):

Thanks I had the same problem, just edit the

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/aanchal');
```

to

```
define('HTTP_SERVER','http://aanchal.site50.net/aanchal');
```

and

```
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://localhost/aanchal');
```

to

```
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://aanchal.site50.net/aanchal');
```

in `configure.php`.